# MS Project 2013 Chart - how to manually set min / max value of X-axis?

Tags: ms-project

When creating a chart in the "Report" tab, I can use the "Format Axis" dialog to manually specify the min/max values when the Y-axis is selected, but I don't see those options when the X-axis is selected.

Is there a way to specify the min/max values for the X-axis?

Thanks in advance for your help!

P.S. Right now I'm using the "Chart Filter" icon (next to the upper right corner of the table) to select the timescale for the X-axis by manually selecting each day that needs to appear, but doing that is very time consuming and I'm hoping that there is a way to just specify the min/max values.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

1. Open the "Field List" dialog ("Design" tab / "Chart Data").
2. Select Category: "Time" & click adjacent "Edit" box (on right).
3. "Edit Timescale" dialog: change the Start and Finish dates to the desired values.